# Getting primary key of each row inside for loop in sql server 2005

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005, triggers, primary-key

I want to write a trigger in SQL Server 2005 in which inside the for loop I want to update every row of a particular table based on its primary key. The problem is how should I get primary key of each row inside for loop?

Please Help

sorry for not mentioning above details

```
  Table  UserPersonalInfo

   UserId       varchar(50) Primary Key                 
   FirstName    varchar(50)         
   MiddleName   varchar(50)         
   LastName         varchar(50)
   UserName         varchar(50)
   Password         varchar(50)
   ContactNo    bigint  
   Verified         bit 
   Address      varchar(100)    
   EmailId      varchar(100)    
   RoleId       int 
   CurrentFine  money   
   Photo        image   

   Table CurrentlyIssuedBook

   Userid   varchar(50) Primary Key
   BookId   varchar(50) 
   IssuedDate   datetime    
   ExpectedReturnDate   datetime    
   ISBN varchar(50) 

 Table CurrentDate

     date datetime
```

Above are the two tables

Now what I am trying to do is...

Everytime I run my C# application I will try to update date in CurrentDate table with actual current date. If the update is successful then the trigger will run.

Inside trigger I want to update fine for each user in the UserPersonalInfo table. For that I have thought of using a loop but how will get primary key value of each row from UserInfo table?

My Fine Calculation logic is a follows

```
totalfine = 0
x =  currentdate - ExpectedReturnDate
y = x/30
z = x%30

for(int i=0; i <y; i++)
{
   totalfine = totalfine + (2^i * 4 * 30);
}

totalfine = totalfine + (2^i * 4 * z);
```

Now please suggest me what should I do?

Comment: What's the schema of the table (name, column names and types, etc)? Which column is the primary key? What exactly are you planning to update on each row, and how does it relate to the primary key?

Comment: Don't use a loop if you can avoid it. It's much slower. Why not just something like `update table set something=key`?

Comment: sorry for not mentioning above details

    Table UserInfo

    UserId varchar(25) Primary Key,
    Name varchar(100),
    dept varchar(50),
    fine money

    Table CurrentDate

    date datetime

Above are the two tables

Now what I am trying to do is

Everytime I run my C# application I will try to update date in CurrentDate table with actual current date. If the update is successful then the trigger will run.

Inside trigger I want to update fine for each user in the UserInfo table. For that I have thought of using a loop but how will get primary key value of each row from UserInfo table?

Comment: @NileshBarai: please **DO NOT** post table details etc. into comments - it's **REALLY HARD** to read..... please **UPDATE** your question by editing it and provide that new information!

Comment: @NileshBarai next time, just edit your question: I did it for you this time.

Comment: Im a bit confused about your comment.  You say when the CurrentDate is changed you then want to update the UserInfo rows.  What is the criteria for updating the UserInfo table or are you just blanket updating all the rows?  Im a bit confused as to why you would use a trigger, cant you just update the date first and then update the user info table in the same SP?

Comment: @RichardHanley: Primary key is in that row but I am not trying to modify it. I want to modify fine

Comment: @RichardHanley: Yes there is criteria for update
I will be finding out the number of days elapsed from a different table. Then I will be applying a formula for calculating fine.
Hence for every user fine will be different.
so i want to use a loop

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a loop.

You can update every row in the table just by using an `update` statement with no `where` clause, eg:

```
declare @currentdate datetime
select @currentdate = date from currentdate

update userinfo
set fine = case when @currentdate < getdate() then 100 else 0 end
```

Of course, I don't know what your fine calculation is, so the above is just a trivial example.

It's possible to put complex calculations involving other tables and so on into an update statement as above, and it will be much faster than a loop. Having said that, if you really want to use a loop, you need to use a cursor. Maybe something like:

```
declare @ID int
declare cur_loop cursor fast_forward for 
    select UserId from UserInfo

open cur_loop
fetch next from cur_loop into @ID
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0 begin
    -- your code here
    update UserInfo set fine = (calculation result) where UserID=@ID
    fetch next from cur_loop into @ID
end
close cur_loop
deallocate cur_loop
```

Comment: There is a calculation which I need to do for finding fine for each user. For every user fine will be different.

Comment: Im probably missunderstanding your design, but does it really need a trigger?  cant you have the update statement in the SP which does the current date insert?

Comment: @RichardHanley: wait I will post the entire required schema for the above problem

Comment: @Blorgbeard: I have modified my question. Please suggest me if the calculation which I have mentioned is possible in single update query?

Answer (score 2):

Cant you do something like this:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER tr_CurrentDateUpdate
   ON  CurrentDate
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE  UserInfo
    SET     fine = 6
    WHERE   userid like '%foo%'

    UPDATE  UserInfo
    SET     fine = 7
    WHERE   userid like '%baa%'

END
GO
```

Where the "where" clauses are your criteria for selecting which users you want to change and the fine = your calculations?

Also, I didnt test this but, if you have your calculation in a UDF I think you could just put something like this where i had my update statements:

```
DECLARE @InsertedDate Datetime

SELECT  @InsertedDate = date
FROM inserted   

UPDATE  u
SET     u.fine = cf.FineResult
FROM    UserInfo u
cross apply dbo.CalculateFine(u.UserId, @InsertedDate) cf
```

Where CalculateFine UDF contains the logic on how to convert the user details into their fine.

With a UDF something like this:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION CalculateFine (@UserId varchar(50), @CurrentDate datetime)
 RETURNS money
 AS
 BEGIN

--TODO  get expected return date ExpectedReturnDate from CurrentlyIssuedBook for that @UserId

--TODO Do you need all these delcarations?
DECLARE @x AS INT
DECLARE @fine AS MONEY
DECLARE @y AS INT
DECLARE @z AS INT

SET @x = DATEDIFF(dd, @CurrentDate, ExpectedReturnDate)
SET @y = @x/30
SET @z = @x%30
-- TODO  convert your logic here....

--Return your answer
RETURN @fine
END
```

Comment: As you have asked earlier I have modified my question

Comment: How will I be able to do this for each user?

Comment: This will be fired when you update the currentdate table and update all rows in the UserInfo table. If you need to pass the "inserted"  date value to your UDF calculation too you can as well.

Comment: But I guess this will update all the user records with a single fine value which I dont want. I have given my fine calculation logic in the question. Taking a look at it you could suggest something

Comment: Put your calculation logic in a UDF and have that calculate the fine.  Call the UDF as i did in the second half of my answer (which i believe should work ok) passing in the parameters needed for your calculation.

Comment: I added a possible UDF to my answer